# How to build .vdproj in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: windows, azure-pipelines, .net-3.5, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am using windows self hosted agent with VS 2019 build tools installed. But in the build pipeline, I am unable to build ".vdproj" (.net framework 3.5) project. Please let me know whether installing of visual studio is the only option or any alternative approach available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To build the .vdproj project, you will have to use devenv command to build the project.

Devenv.exe is the central Integrated Development Environment (IDE) for Visual Studio.

So you need to install the Visual Studio to get the Devenv.exe to build the project.

In Azure DevOps, you can add the Command Line Task and run the following command to build the .vdproj project.

For example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" MyProjectDir\MySolution.sln /Rebuild Release
```

Comment: Hi Kim, The above command is not working for me, when I am trying to execute using VS Professional. May I know how to find the root cause? Because when I open the IDE and build the setup project, it is generating the MSI. But it is not working when I try to generate it using devenv command.